# Want to select a non aggregate function

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 4 tables:

student:

```
student_id(PK)
student_name
section_ID
```

section:

```
section_ID(PK)
section
```

class:

```
class_ID(PK)
class
section_ID
```

marks:

```
student_id(CK)
subject_id(CK)
marks
```

With the following code

```
SELECT Class.Class, MAX(Marks.Marks) AS Total_Marks
FROM Marks, Class, Student, Section
WHERE Marks.Student_ID = Student.Student_ID
AND Student.Section_ID = Section.Section_ID
AND Section.Section_ID = Class.Section_ID
GROUP BY Class.Class
```

I'm able to find the highest marks from every class but I want to display the name of the student too OR studentID

Help me out please
I'm using MS ACCESS

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: I'm using MS ACCESS so this is the best I'm suitable with

Comment: . . So what?  MS Access supports `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, and `RIGHT JOIN`.

Comment: You can use one of the methods shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56799047/7531598), substituting marks for date.

Answer (score -1):

```
select st.student_name, max(marks)
    from student st, student_id s, section s
    where marks= (select max(marks)
    from student_id) and s.student_id = st.student_id
and st.section_id = s.section_id
group by st.student_name
```