# Joining two query results

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following tables:

Class:

```
Class_ID (PK)
Class
Section_ID
```

Section:

```
Section_ID (PK)
Section
Teacher_ID
```

Subject:

```
Subject_ID (PK)
Subject_Name
Section_ID
```

Marks:

```
Student_ID (CK)
Subject_ID (CK)
```

Student:

```
Student_ID (PK)
Student_Name
Section_ID
```

Teacher:

```
Teacher_ID (PK)
Teacher_Name
Subject_ID
```

I have the following two queries generated,

This one for showing Marks of each student from each class and section

```
SELECT 
    Marks.Student_ID, Class, Section.Section, Subject.Subject_Name, Marks.Marks
FROM 
    Marks, Student, [Section], Class, Subject
WHERE 
    Marks.Student_ID=Student.Student_ID 
    AND Student.Section_ID = Section.Section_ID 
    AND Section.Section_ID = Class.Section_ID 
    AND Marks.Subject_ID = Subject.Subject_ID
GROUP BY 
    Marks.Student_ID, Section.Section_ID, Section.Section, Class.Class, Marks.Marks, Subject.Subject_Name
```

And this one for for highest marks in a class in each subject

```
SELECT 
    Class.Class, Subject.Subject_Name,MAX(Marks.Marks) AS Total_Marks
FROM 
    Marks, Class, Student, [Section], Subject
WHERE 
    Marks.Student_ID = Student.Student_ID 
    AND Student.Section_ID = Section.Section_ID 
    AND Section.Section_ID = Class.Section_ID 
    AND Marks.Subject_ID = Subject.Subject_ID
GROUP BY 
    Class.Class, Subject.Subject_Name
```

I want to generate a query which can show the student_id for the second query having the highest marks from each class in each subject

I guess joining the upper two queries can do the trick but other suggestions are most welcome, since I've just started learning SQL and MS Access.

Comment: Instead of WHERE should probably use JOIN clause. Access query designer should help get syntax correct. Then compound JOIN the two queries and tell us what happens. Why use GROUP BY clause in first query? I don't see data aggregation.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**over 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Want to select a non aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56851519/want-to-select-a-non-aggregate-function)

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment by June7 you should probably use INNER JOINs rather than these cross joins, but both work, and it is just a taste thing.

And you are already correct in that you will just want to connect both queries. Your top score query needs only to return the ID fields rather than any text, and then include it as a subquery in your first query.

If you are using saved queries in Access then the Query builder makes it all very easy to visualise.

If not and you want to use SQL then insert the subquery by putting the SQL code for the subquery in brackets and then giving it an alias. You can then treat it like a table.

`FROM Marks, Student, [Section], Class, Subject, (SELECT.... ) TopMarks
    WHERE ...
      AND TopMarks.SubjectID = Subject.SubjectID AND TopMarks.ClassID = Class.ClassID`

Easier to visualise with INNER JOINS. In fact I don't remember ever doing it this way with your joining method. CROSS JOINs, OUTER JOINs. It has many names.